# Apex Classes : No components available in my Org Browser Metadata

Tags: salesforce, metadata

I've successfully set up a connection between my Salesforce org and my project in VS Code. However, when attempting to access the metadata ( ORG BROWSER : Metadata )  related to Apex classes within the project, I'm encountering a message indicating that "no component is available." for the other things too ( like Apex Triggers .. lightning web components ... ) Can someone explain me why ?
thanks a lot

I tried SFDX : Refresh sObject definitons